While Loop to find all objects in database in hierarchy order form child to parent
I cannot use a recursive CTE as I have some children which refer to parent and parent to child.
I need to list all the tables related by FK from child to parent in order to create delete statement.
My idea is to do it like this:
Find all the tables then find all the tables on leaf level then save them to temptable run next iteration and find all parents without those table so if the table already exist in my tempt table it won't be taken to consideration that way i should avoid the issue described in first step, but I don't know how to do that? Maybe some of you had similar problem and wants to share a solution?
To get a list of the table from oldest child to newest parent in order to delete statement from child to parent, I don't want to remove indexes.
SELECT
    SCHEMA_NAME(pt.schema_id) + '.' + pt.name AS foreign_table
    , fk.name AS foreign_key_name
    , SCHEMA_NAME(pt.schema_id) + '.' + pt.name AS parent_table_name
    , pc.name AS parent_column_name
    , SCHEMA_NAME(ct.schema_id) + '.' + ct.name AS referenced_table_name
    , cc.name AS referenced_column_name --INTO #StateSKForeginTables
    , ct.object_id
FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
    ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables pt
    ON pt.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns pc
    ON fkc.parent_column_id = pc.column_id
    AND pc.object_id = pt.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables ct
    ON ct.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns cc
    ON cc.object_id = ct.object_id
    AND fkc.referenced_column_id = cc.column_id
ORDER BY pt.name, pc.name

By CTE I'm getting error:

The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

WITH dependencies -- Get object with FK dependencies
AS (
    SELECT FK.TABLE_NAME AS Obj
        , PK.TABLE_NAME AS Depends
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK
        ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK
        ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    ), 
no_dependencies -- The first level are objects with no dependencies 
AS (
    SELECT 
        name AS Obj
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT obj FROM dependencies) --we remove objects with dependencies from first CTE
    AND type = 'U' -- Just tables
    ) 

--SELECT * FROM no_dependencies -- znajude mi widoki widokow nie chce.

,recursiv -- recursive CTE to get dependencies
AS (
    SELECT Obj AS [Table]
        , CAST('' AS VARCHAR(max)) AS DependsON
        , 0 AS LVL -- Level 0 indicate tables with no dependencies
    FROM no_dependencies
 
    UNION ALL
 
    SELECT d.Obj AS [Table]
        , CAST(IIF(LVL > 0, r.DependsON + ' > ', '') + d.Depends AS VARCHAR(max)) -- visually reflects hierarchy
        , R.lvl + 1 AS LVL
    FROM dependencies d
    INNER JOIN recursiv r
        ON d.Depends = r.[Table]
    )
-- The final result with each table only shown once
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(O.schema_id) AS [TableSchema]
    , R.[Table]
    , max(R.LVL) as LVL
FROM recursiv R
INNER JOIN sys.objects O
    ON R.[Table] = O.name
GROUP BY O.schema_id, R.[Table]
ORDER BY LVL
    , R.[Table]


What would be your intended result? You say "to create delete statement" what exactly are you trying to do? I'm guessing your database has a circular FK either on the same table, or between two or more.

Im trying to get a list of tables from child to parent in order to create a delete statements later for that list, but i need to list tables in hierarchical order, and beacuse I have circuralFK that's the problem that's my recursive cte is throwing an error and I don't know how to do that

Yeah, can you show that delete statement along with table definitions? I think there is a way to generate the whole statement but I can't see exactly what yo are doing.

See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/317184/220697. You need to be clear about what you want to achieve: do you want to implement cascading deletes, or do you only want to delete where there is no child? And which version of SQL Server?

lets say i have a table a  which refers to table b by fk and then table c refers to b by FK
I want to delete records like that
delete from table c
delete record from table b
delete record from table a
but i need to have them from leaf level to root to avoid issue on delete reference to foregin key
and i want to for all database table (i want to add later a where so I want to delete rows which has specific time of load for example like to delete ivalid load rows from all tables)

Don't "let's say" please, just show it, [edit] your post with the details, not in a comment. Table definitions, with PKs and FKs, and sample data, and step by step what you want to happen.

I think I described the problem enough I want to use while loop to get list of table from child to parent in order to create delete statments later

You don't need a while loop, your existing rCTE is mostly fine. You need to add a check for self-referencing FKs AND d.[Table] <> d.Depends (although you should probably compare by object_id) and you may also want to check for a larger circular reference A->B->A or A->B->C although that's unusual in a good database design.
